# Hadoop Chain Jobs - Skip second Job if input files does not exit

Tags: hadoop

I have two hadoop jobs. First Job saves output in hdfs file an the second job has as input this file. When this file does not exist i have error. How can i skip the second job if first jobs outfile does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Use this test, but with the path created by the first job:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
String inputDir= "HDFS file path";  
if (fs.exists(new Path(inputDir))) { 

    // this block gets executed only if the file path inputDir exists

}
```

The code inside the block would contain the configuration and execution code for the second job.

Comment: If i want to check for a file and not folder?

Comment: @EleftheriosK., Any luck resolving this problem?